# Is it possible to actually verify a “sponge function” security claim?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, sha-3, sponge

When using a “sponge function” to create a cryptographic hash, we can look at the flat sponge claim, which flattens the claimed success probabilities of all attacks using a single parameter: the claimed capacity *c*<sub>claim</sub>

Is there any way to actually verify the probability of that claim - in this case: potential probability of collisions of the “sponge function”-based cryptographic hash - and what would such a proof formula/calculation look like?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After spending more than two weeks reading well over 750 pages while checking the following (PDF) documents…

- [Sponge Functions](http://sponge.noekeon.org/SpongeFunctions.pdf)
- [Cryptographic sponge functions](http://sponge.noekeon.org/CSF-0.1.pdf)
- [Security Analysis of Extended Sponge Functions](http://www.lorentzcenter.nl/lc/web/2008/309/presentations/Peyrin.pdf)
- [Cryptographic Hash Functions: Recent Design Trends and
  Security Notions](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/565.pdf)
- [On the Implementation Aspects of Sponge-based
  Authenticated Encryption for Pervasive Devices](http://cardis.iaik.tugraz.at/proceedings/cardis_2012/CARDIS2012_11.pdf)
- [On the security of the keyed sponge construction](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Round2/Aug2010/documents/papers/VANASSCHE_SpongeKeyed.pdf)
- [Keccak and the SHA-3 Standardization](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/documents/Keccak-slides-at-NIST.pdf)
- [Computer Science and Its Applications: Csa 2012](http://books.google.de/books?id=CDFxHUtUj2cC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en)

…it turns out that the probability of the claim can only be *"proven"* theoretically. In other words: currently, there is no way to actually and/or practically verify the probability of the claim.

The current status quo states that collisions are theoretically proven to be *very unlikely* in a cryptographic sense. I guess that — as with all cryptographic theories — only time can tell if that actually provides a problem or not.

But, getting back to my question: no, it can't actually be verified currently.

I don't expect this to change anytime soon either, as the theoretical proof that collisions are *very unlikely* in a cryptographic sense, seems to be strong enough to regard sponge functions as (let's just call it) *"secure"*. In fact, if you check the linked documents, you will find ample information on how to replicate the theoretical proofs in relation to collision probabilities using sponge functions under a multitude of conditions. As far as I checked, cross-checked, and even practically used those formulas to verify things myself, I got convinced that collisions are indeed *very (**very**) unlikely*.

I hope you don't mind that I'm sparing you a copy-and-paste job of more than a dozen of pages full of math code. Those who want to dive in deeper, can fetch the multitude of related formulas and a truckload of additional, interesting information from the linked documents I listed above.